# how can I access a global variable from another .py file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I created two files, and when I run `a.py`, result is `{'1': '1'}`, it's correct. however, running `b.py`, the result is none.  How can I get the value of requests from `b.py`?

a.py:

```
requests = {}

def set_value():
   global requests
   requests["1"] = "1"

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    set_value()
    print(requests)
```

b.py:

```
import a

def get_value():
   print(a.requests)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   get_value()
```

Comment: `__name__ == "__main__"` is false if the file containing it was imported from another file.

Comment: You need to call `set_vale` to get `1:1` added to `requests`.  Importing `a` doesn't do this.  So from `b`, you can call `a.set_vale()` before calling `get_value`.

Comment: It is returning null because set_vale() is not called whenever get_value() is called in b.py.

Try calling set_vale() in get_value() of b.py.

Answer (score 1):

`if __name__ == "__main__":` means that the code following it will only be executed when the file is called explicitly with `python3 filename.py` from the command line.  Since you are simply importing your file and not executing it, the `global` variable is never set.

Also, python variables are all "global" variables when declared outside of a function, and the `global` keyword is only needed when you want to declare a global variable *inside* of a function.

To fix this, change `a.py` to the following:

```
requests = {}

def set_vale():
    requests["1"] = "1"

set_vale()
```